# breaking down causes for a 404 response in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interceptor in angular grabbing my HTTP errors like so:

```
angular.module("app")
.factory("interceptor", function($q) {
  // omitted for brevity.
  responseError: function(response) {
    switch(response.status) {
      case 404:
        // here be the problem
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    $q.reject(response);
  }
})
.config(["$httpProvider",
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("interceptor");
  }
]);
```

The problem I am having is that a 404 can result from multiple things. For example, a CSS sheet missing might cause a 404, or an image missing. However, what I am particularly targetting is if the *template* for a given route is missing and isolating this case.

Is it possible to break down the causes of the 404 error and extract if it was a template not found error?

---

EDIT: I took a look at `$route` in angular, and tried to get the current route's `templateUrl` and compare it.

```
if(response.url == $route.current.templateUrl) { /** ... */ }
```

However, I got a circular import when I included it, and undefined when I did not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your interceptor will only apply to files accessed in your app via `$http`. Meaning that a 404 caused by a missing stylesheet embedded in the head of your document will never be captured by your interceptor. What you'll mostly get in your interceptor are ajax requests to web services, and requests for html templates.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that templates have an `.html` extension and are the only objects with that extension.

```
angular.module("app")
.factory("interceptor", function($q) {
  // omitted for brevity.
  responseError: function(response) {
    switch(response.status) {
      case 404:
        // Check the config object, look for ".html"
        // in the url string
        if(response.config.url.indexOf('.html') !== -1){
          // It's an html document
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    $q.reject(response);
  }
})
.config(["$httpProvider",
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("interceptor");
  }
]);
```

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. I tried to get `$route.current.templateUrl` and compare it but got a circular import error on that